# Mule - Returning data from multiple flows as soon as it's ready

Tags: ajax, mule, esb

Hello there Stack Overflow.

My scenario is that I have a web page where a user can enter data (search terms, such as the name of a product on sale, a category, etc). On submission, this data is sent to the Mule ESB which then uses it to query two (or more) databases. One of these databases is rather quick and returns data fast, but the other is slow and can take a minute or longer to come back with information (if it doesn't timeout).

Currently, Mule is waiting to collect results from all flows before sending any information back to the web browser which made the query.

My problem is that this creates a very bad experience for the user - especially if the product that they're looking for is not in a database. They could be waiting quite a while before receiving anything back.

My current flow is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyyI0.png

I have attempted to experiment with asynchronous flows but have never got them to send back data as and when it's ready.

Is there any way in Mule to return results from multiple flows as soon as the result is available? I would like to display the results for each query/flow as and when they come in, rather than waiting for all flows to terminate before sending data back to the user's browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option for your use case, if I understood it correctly, would be to use asynchronous processing and return the results through the Ajax transport: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/AJAX+Transport+Reference 
This way you can return immediately to the client and publish results when you get them in the Ajax channel.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've dug around in the docs before but seemingly skimmed over that page. I've got it working just as I envisioned - results are sent to the client as soon as they're available.